# WSO2 API Manager star without slash

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to setup up different resources as separate apis in the WSO2 API manager, examples being http://www.test.com/test/car and http://www.test.com/test/bike so instead of them all falling under a test API I am creating a car and a bike api separately so people only have access to specific resources in the API.

The problem I am having is with query parameters I can't get it to accept query parameters on the end without putting a slash after the resource ie http://www.test.com/test/bike/?id=123 the query parameters are many so I don't want to specify them I want it to accept anything after the resource.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what api manager version are you used?

Comment: @lakshman I am using 1.9

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I checked your scenario by creating API an invoking it with several query params, I can get the response without any issue. what  is the response you get after invoking your API with several query params?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get any query parameter accepted by defining my resource path as given below

```
/car*
```

Doing above will enforces synapse to append any resource path.

Then I used Advanced Rest Client to call the API using below given URL

https://localhost:8243/test/1.0.0/car?id=1

By following above steps I was able to call the API successfully without specifying query parameters while designing the API using API Manager Publisher

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this was a known issue in API Manager 1.9.1, and it has been fixed in version 1.10, which you can download [here](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/), or use online as [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud).